# Changing the 'Omer sign

Tags: halacha, blessing, sefirat-ha-omer

If a Shul has an 'Omer sign that is manually changed, may someone change it before making the Berachah on the night's count?

If not, and if the solution is to change it before Bein HaShemashoth, can this be done on Shabbath for the Motzei Shabbath count?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting the Omer non-verbally](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/counting-the-omer-non-verbally)

Comment: @GershonGold Certainly the second question is not.

Comment: duplicate http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17580/is-it-allowed-to-prepare-for-maariv-after-shabbos-during-the-rabbinic-tosefes-sh

Comment: @GershonGold, Thanks.  I tried to find that one; I thought it might have been asked before.

Comment: I believe that there is a practical (if not halachic) difference between putting on a talis and changing the sign.  I will vote to close, but I think Seth J can edit the post to leave Q2 in as a related, but not du[plicate, case.

Comment: ["Counting the Omer non-verbally"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15763) asks about signing (in sign language) or writing the count; this, about moving a plate into place, potentially a weaker act and certainly a different one. I'm disinclined to close as duplicate.

Comment: @GershonGold It's certainly not a duplicate the second time because that question is asking about hachana from tosefet shabbat to maariv. This is asking about from before bein hashemashot to maariv.

Comment: I second @msh210. Also, whether a mute person can be yotzei Sefirah with writing, doesn't mean a speaking person will be when he writes the Sefirah, especially if he doesn't have in mind to be yotzei with it.